# How to change Winform TabControl location

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I need to change an already made winform application. 
This application has a tab control statically made with the designer. This functions as the main input/output for the app and is located at the very top of the windows.

I want to lower it a bit (the upper left corner) and add a MenuStrip above the tab control.

When I try to change the location property in the designer window (currently X and Y are set to 0), It just won't change the values I enter and change it automatically back to 0.

How can I change the tab's location so I can add a menu strip above it?

Comment: Is the tab control docked to the container? Check its `Dock` property.

Comment: It's docked to the top. If I try to change it, everything gets messy there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you like to add `MenuStrip` to top but `TabControl` accommodates top position.

It doesn't matter when you add a `MenuStrip` it always goes to top. Try it.

Comment: HA! I feel like an Idiot right now.. I was sure you need to stretch it over the designer page where you want it to be located.